# Consolidating VBA IF, THEN statements that repeat the same logic in a continuous row set

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I am a novice when it comes to writing macro code in VBA.  I'm working with Excel 2010, and I think I have a simple problem.  I want to hide rows in my worksheet that meet the condition of having a zero sum result in column AJ.  I was able to figure how to do this for one row and then repeat for each subsequent row, but I know there must a better/more efficient means of writing this.  Can anyone help me re-word this code so that it considers  the range of rows 8-14 all together rather than considering each row one at a time?  This would reduce my run-time and decrease the possibility for errors.  Thank you in advance!

```
Sub Hide_1()
'

' Master Macro
     If ActiveSheet.Range("AJ8") = 0 Then
        Rows("8").EntireRow.Hidden = True
     End If

    If ActiveSheet.Range("AJ9") = 0 Then
        Rows("9").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If

    If ActiveSheet.Range("AJ10") = 0 Then
        Rows("10").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If

    If ActiveSheet.Range("AJ11") = 0 Then
        Rows("11").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If

    If ActiveSheet.Range("AJ12") = 0 Then
        Rows("12").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If

    If ActiveSheet.Range("AJ13") = 0 Then
        Rows("13").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If

    If ActiveSheet.Range("AJ14") = 0 Then
        Rows("14").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will loop through your range and hide the row where the value is 0:

```
Sub HideRows()
    Dim rng As Range, cl As Range

    Set rng = Range("AJ8:AJ14")

    For Each cl In rng
        If cl = 0 Then
            cl.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If
    Next cl
End Sub
```

Comment: Perfect solution for what I needed, as this command must be repeated several dozen times and for different ranges from 300 - 800 rows at a time. I learned a lot! Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
Public Sub HideEntireRow(cellToCheck As range, valueToHide As Variant)
    If cellToCheck.Value2 = valueToHide Then cellToCheck.EntireRow.Hidden = True
End Sub

Public Sub Hide_2()
    Dim cell As range
    For Each cell In ActiveSheet.range("AJ10:AJ14")
        Call HideEntireRow(cell, 0)
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

For a range as small as you are working with, an autofilter will not offer any visible performance boost, but you should use autofilters by default rather than loops. There are plenty of instances where loops are necessary, but this doesn't appear to be one of them.

Here is how you can filter your sheet (starting in row 8), hiding any rows that have a 0 in column AJ. Note that I am calculating the last row in your sheet. If you need to hard-code a specific range, you can easily modify this:

```
Sub FilterZeroRows()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    lastRow = ws.Range("AJ" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = ws.Range("AJ8:AJ" & lastRow)
    ' keep any rows that don't have 0 visible
    rng.AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="<>0"
End Sub
```